# what is the meaning of below verilog code

Tags: verilog

Can someone please tell me the meaning of this verilog code:

```
parameter data2 = 4;  
reg [data2-1:0] data1;
if(data1=={data2{1'b0}})
```

Comment: At first inspection, this is my initial guess. Take data2, append a zero on the end and compare it to data1.

Comment: If you added more information about variables... Maybe if _data1_ is 1bit wide, then take one bit (bit0) of _data2_ and compare to data1?

Comment: This is not a productive way to program. You've written something at random, you don't know what it means, and you want someone else to tell you?

Comment: Unless `data2` is a parameter or define, this is not synthesizable code.

Comment: How is `data2` described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically *would* mean "if data1 equals a value of 0".

The reason I say "would" is that the code is likely not synthesisable. You appear to be trying to use the concatenation operator in a way which is not allowed.

---

The code:

```
{x{y}}
```

means, "concatenate x copies of y". So if you were to do:

```
{10{1'b0}}
```

It would be equivalent to `10'b0000000000`.

Similarly:

```
{4{2'b10}}
```

Is equivalent to `8'b10101010` because it concatenates 4 copies of the value `2'b10`.

This is a useful construct if you have a parameterised constant. For example:

```
localparam WIDTH = 4;
wire [WIDTH-1:0] someWire;
assign someWire = {WIDTH{1'b0}};
```

That would assign a value of 0 to all bits of `someWire` with a constant whose width changes with the parameter `WIDTH`.

---

Now as to your case. Unless `data2` is a constant (i.e. `localparam`, `parameter`, or `'define`), then you are basically asking for a value of `0` whose width changes as `data2` changes value. Clearly this makes no sense at all as the hardware cannot dynamically reconfigure.